# How can I create a Panel with contents for each MySQL fetched variable

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, foreach, reader

I've been searching the web for hours to find a solution to this. I use a `MySqlDataReader` to fetch some variables from the database and I want to create a `foreach` loop to create a `HyperLink` for every id that I have fetched. In this `HyperLink` I need to set a `Image` depending on the grade of every id, a `Label` for the name and another `Label` for the grade's name.

Here is the CodeBehind:

```
connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ToString();
conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
queryStr = "SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE account_id=?id LIMIT 5";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", IdKeeper.Value);
conn.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
foreach (string "id fetched" in PanelID)
{
    //Stuck here!!!
}
reader.Close();
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5(v=vs.85).aspx) on your aspx page.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1">
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("dbColumnName") %>'></asp:Label>: </td>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("dbColumnName") %>'>Click Me</asp:HyperLink></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

And then bind the data directly to the Repeater in code behind without the need for a foreach loop.

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Repeater1.DataSource = reader;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello and thanks for responding. I used a `Repeater` as you suggested but data is not displayed. In the `Inspect element` option of my browser there is no controller with the `ID` of Label1 or HyperLink1. I did a little searching about `MySql` connections on `Repeaters` but no luck... Here is my latest code:

ASPX:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" CssClass="main-content-content" ID="AllCharacters">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col1") %></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col2") %></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col3") %></td>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

C#:

```
queryStr = "SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE id=?id LIMIT 1";
cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?id", IdKeeper.Value);
conn.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
Repeater1.DataSource = reader;
Repeater1.DataBind();
reader.Close();
```

**UPDATE:**
After commenting the `reader.Read();` line the code worked, but only for the first row fetched by `reader` while there are 2 with the same `id`. I tried to create another `<ItemTemplate>` tag same as the first but no luck...